# Google Analytics utme tag

Tags: google-analytics, tagging

So I am trying to track some tags and I came across this really ugly number for the utme tags for all of my pages. It looks like a custom event tag but I cannot tell what the numbers represent, or if they represent anything at all.

Looks like this: 
utme: 14(1000*0*0*90*0*0*700*700)(1003*0*0*90*0*0*702*703)

Any random numbers after 14. They area also different every time the tag fires.

Please help.